# How do I fix a "url downloading" script that errors, "AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'"?

Tags: python, urllib

I'm not too experienced in coding, so I need some help. There's a python script that I downloaded that's supposed to download images based on a custom URL[the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdWnA.png). Whenever I run it, nothing happens. I looked into it, and I got the error message "AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'" Why is this, and how can I make it work?

I've tried looking around for this problem, but nothing has been as specific as I need it.

Comment: It should be `urllib.request.urlretrieve`. If you go to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) and enter `urlretrieve` into the search field, you'll see this.

Comment: I think this script was written for Python 2.x. So it may have lots of other compatibility problems. You should find something newer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). If the script is copyrighted, then make a [mre] in its place, which might be as simple as `urllib.urlretrieve('https://google.com', 'google.html')`. BTW, check out [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: **DO NOT** use screenshots for showing your code or the output of running the code if that output is just text. Screenshots are hard to read and we cannot copy/paste the text in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're encountering, `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'`, suggests that there's a problem with the way the script is attempting to use the urllib module. Specifically, it seems like the script is trying to use the urlretrieve function from urllib, but it's not finding it.

This could be due to a version mismatch or a change in how Python libraries work. urlretrieve [used to be a part of urllib in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve), but [in Python 3, it was moved to urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve).

try these commands

Old import (Python 2)

```
import urllib
```

New import (Python 3)

```
import urllib.request
```

Old usage

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

New usage

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Comment: I suspect this won't be the only compatibility problem.

Comment: This is a decent answer, but I'm not sure what you're not sure about when you say "**suggests** that there's a problem" and "it **seems** like the script is trying to ...". Was this partly written by AI? If so, [that's not allowed on Stack Overflow](/help/ai-policy) so you should delete this answer if possible or at least remove the explanation from the AI (everything above "try these commands") and replace it with your own in order to avoid [plagiarizing](/help/referencing).

Comment: no, it's not written by AI, this works for him

Comment: @MANI What do you mean by "this works for him"?

Comment: I would upvote your answer, but I need 15 reputation :P